# Не удается установить vmware 12 на fedora 25

Tags: linux, vmware, fedora

OS Fedora 25
Kernel `4.9.13-200.fc25.x86_64`

Ввожу команду

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Ошибки:

```
Stopping vmware (via systemctl):                           [  OK  ]
make: вход в каталог «/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only»
Using kernel build system.
/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.9.13-200.fc25.x86_64/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: вход в каталог «/usr/src/kernels/4.9.13-200.fc25.x86_64»
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c: В функции «HostIFGetUserPages»:
/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1166:67: ошибка: в передаче аргумента 5 «get_user_pages»: несовместимый тип указателя [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
    retval = get_user_pages((unsigned long)uvAddr, numPages, 0, 0, ppages, NULL);
                                                                   ^~~~~~
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./include/linux/mm.h:1280:6: замечание: ожидался тип «struct vm_area_struct **», но аргумент имеет тип «struct page **»
 long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:1166:13: ошибка: слишком много аргументов в вызове функции «get_user_pages»
    retval = get_user_pages((unsigned long)uvAddr, numPages, 0, 0, ppages, NULL);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/./include/compat_page.h:23:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./include/linux/mm.h:1280:6: замечание: объявлено здесь
 long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1283:1: предупреждение: always_inline функция, возможно, не годится для подстановки [-Wattributes]
 LinuxDriverSyncReadTSCs(uint64 *delta) // OUT: TSC max - TSC min
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/common/task.o
cc1: некоторые предупреждения считаются ошибками
scripts/Makefile.build:293: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o»
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o] Ошибка 1
make[2]: *** Ожидание завершения заданий…
/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only/common/task.o: warning: objtool: .text: unexpected end of section
Makefile:1494: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «_module_/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only»
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only] Ошибка 2
make[1]: выход из каталога «/usr/src/kernels/4.9.13-200.fc25.x86_64»
Makefile:120: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «vmmon.ko»
make: *** [vmmon.ko] Ошибка 2
make: выход из каталога «/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmmon-only»
make: вход в каталог «/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only»
Using kernel build system.
/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.9.13-200.fc25.x86_64/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: вход в каталог «/usr/src/kernels/4.9.13-200.fc25.x86_64»
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/netif.o
/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/userif.c: В функции «UserifLockPage»:
/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/userif.c:117:43: ошибка: в передаче аргумента 5 «get_user_pages»: несовместимый тип указателя [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
    retval = get_user_pages(addr, 1, 1, 0, &page, NULL);
                                           ^
In file included from ./include/linux/highmem.h:7:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
./include/linux/mm.h:1280:6: замечание: ожидался тип «struct vm_area_struct **», но аргумент имеет тип «struct page **»
 long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/userif.c:117:13: ошибка: слишком много аргументов в вызове функции «get_user_pages»
    retval = get_user_pages(addr, 1, 1, 0, &page, NULL);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/highmem.h:7:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/userif.c:26:
./include/linux/mm.h:1280:6: замечание: объявлено здесь
 long get_user_pages(unsigned long start, unsigned long nr_pages,
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:35:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2253:0: предупреждение: «PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE» переопределён
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/netif.c:42:
/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: замечание: это расположение предыдущего определения
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD

cc1: некоторые предупреждения считаются ошибками
scripts/Makefile.build:293: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/userif.o»
make[2]: *** [/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only/userif.o] Ошибка 1
make[2]: *** Ожидание завершения заданий…
Makefile:1494: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «_module_/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only»
make[1]: *** [_module_/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only] Ошибка 2
make[1]: выход из каталога «/usr/src/kernels/4.9.13-200.fc25.x86_64»
Makefile:120: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «vmnet.ko»
make: *** [vmnet.ko] Ошибка 2
make: выход из каталога «/tmp/modconfig-yWthRK/vmnet-only»
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.
```

Comment: Данная проблема повторилась в Fedora 31 Workstation, решил аналогичным путем через `vmnet` и `vmmon`, спасибо +1

Comment: https://sudobeer.com/how-to-install-vmware-workstation-12-on-fedora-26-linux-easy-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему патчем исходников `vmnet` и `vmmon`, сам правил. Все заработало

Answer (score 0):

Данная проблема решена для ядра 4.9.хх
https://communities.vmware.com/message/2644813#2644813
Я устанавливал так:

```
1. root

2. VMware-Workstation-12.5.2-4638234.x86_64.bundle

3. ./VMware-Player-12.5.2-4638234_Linux-4.9_patch.sh

4. bash -x vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Пару апдэйтов федоры прошли безболезненно, но на  4.9.11-200.fc25.x86_64 x86_64
"пропал" vmnet, снос и переустановка vmware не помогали, бил в бубен. Неожиданно всё опять заработало( не могу уточнить причину), сейчас не апдейчусь, пока плаваю на 4.9.11-200

Comment: Решил проблему патчем исходников vmnet и vmmon, сам правил. Все заработало